# Adding new Workbook in VBA crashes Excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

When running VBA macro code

```
Sub x()
 Workbooks.Add
End Sub
```

Excel 2013 goes to "Not Responding".

If I run Add method with some template e.g. Workbooks.Add("C:\book1.xlsx") new workbook based on template is created successfully.

When I try to generate code by macro generator for new workbook creation, same macro as I posted is created. But result of run of this recorded macro is same as running my code - Excel 2013 freezes.

How to solve this? Code was working without issue in Excel 2007.

Comment: might be that the default template is corrupted or missing. Can you try to create a new blank workbook from Excel (outside of VBA)?

Comment: This was possible - I was able to create new workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to uninstall and install Office 2013 again to solve this issue. Installation repair did not helped.

Whole story: I had installed Office 2003, Office 2007. Then I wanted to install Office 2013 (new customer request). Installer of Office 2013 complied about corrupted installation of Office 2003 and thus I needed to uninstall Office 2003 before installation could processed. To be on the save side I uninstalled Office 2007 as part of installation process of Office 2013. Installation was completed successfully but as I discovered later, not all was working as expected...

Comment: IIRC, MS has always recommended against multiple installs of Office, while allowing them, they basically say you can do so at your own risk and that it's not really supported functionality.

Comment: Ok, so as a developer who must be able to test VBA code against different Office versions (based on customers) what should I do? Should I have Virtual Machines with different Office installed on? Or is there any better recommended solution? Moreover as I uninstall Office 2007 as part of Office 2013 installation I would suppose that this could be in fact considered as clean Office 2013 install.

Comment: VM  or dedicated separate hardware.  I've got one laptop running 2010, another 2013, and another 2003 but I haven't had to use the 2003 box in several years.